# Socket.io TypeScript on the server

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io

I'm going through the [TypeScript documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/typescript/) and it says to set up your types and instantiate the `io` via:

```
const io = new Server<
  ClientToServerEvents,
  ServerToClientEvents,
  InterServerEvents,
  SocketData
>();
```

Well in my case I'm doing something like:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server<
ClientToServerEvents,
ServerToClientEvents,
InterServerEvents,
SocketData
>(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: [
      'http://localhost:3000',
      ...
    ],
  },
});
```

Which gives me the TypeScript error:

`Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.`
`(alias) interface InterServerEvents`

Any idea how to fix?